# C++ calling C# function that returns a Class Object

Tags: c#, c++, regasm

I have a class in C#

```
public class RequestInfo
{
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling a C# function from C++

```
TResult.RequestInfo RequestInfo();
```

I registered the C# using REGASM which created a TLB file and on C++ compile I get a TLH file.

RequestInfo in C++ is shown as follows in the generated TLH file:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("e2e15930-fd1a-31de-a166-bf330e327677"))
/* dual interface */ _RequestInfo;
```

and the C# function as follows in the TLH File:

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall RequestInfo (
    /*[out,retval]*/ struct _RequestInfo * * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

I call the C# function from C++ as follows:

```
_RequestInfo *info;
pICS->RequestInfo(&info);
```

The function is called and no errors generated; however:

1. I do not know if I am defining the **info** variable correctly
2. I do not know how to read the **info** variable with the data that the C# function filled.

Help Please!

Comment: Looks right so far. You can look at the generated TLH to see what the RequestInfo class looks like on the C++ side. Probably something use something like info->GetName( &name ); and name would be a BSTR type

Comment: The #import directive you used also generated a TLI file to make this easier to write.  And smart pointers that take care of the memory management, `_RequestInfoPtr` for this one.   Can't really ignore `_com_error`, the exception that is raised when a call fails.  The essential landing page for these auto-generated declarations and support classes [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx).

Comment: the problem is that i have (in TLI file) define inline _bstr_t IRequestInfo::Getbarcode ( ) BUT the return value of the RequestInfo is _RequestInfoPtr